# NDB projection of instance Key or ID

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore

I'm using NDB on GoogleAppEngine and I want to retrieve a instance Key or ID by passing an e-mail into the query.

My Model looks something like this:

```
class Users(ndb.Model):
    user_name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_email = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    user_password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)

    @classmethod
    def get_password_by_email(cls, email):
        return Users.query(Users.user_email == email).get(projection=[Users.key, Users.user_password])
```

When running the code, I get the following error:

```
BadProjectionError: Projecting on unknown property __key__
```

How can I get an instance ID or Key by querying users through an e-mail in AppEngine's NDB (e.g. Login process)?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling that _You're Probably Storing Passwords Incorrectly_ http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html

Comment: Why? I'm not storing it as plain text...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A projection query will always include the key as well as the fields you specify, so if keys_only isn't sufficient, then:

```
return Users.query(Users.user_email == email).get(projection=[Users.password])
```

Answer (score 5):

If you only need Key you can try keys-only query:

```
Users.query(Users.user_email == email).get(keys_only=True)
```